# React Native Mapbox with Expo - App freezes after opening map a second time

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mapbox

Currently, I'm rewriting my web-application to a React Native application using Expo. I've managed to get the map working and rendering correctly when I open the correct screen (using rnmapbox/maps#main).

However, when I navigate away from this screen (using tab navigation) and then open it back up again, the app just freezes and later Android tells me that the app is not responding.

I first thought it was because I had `detachInactiveScreens={false}` on my Stack Navigator, but disabling that doesn't change the problem.

I'm using the MapBox implementation of the map., if that makes a difference at all.

Could this be due to emulation? I don't have an physical android device to test on right now. I've looked found an similar issue on here and found something about having components in my map, however, even without any components in my map, it still does the same thing.

My current code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { GlobalStyles } from '../../../Constants/theme';

import MapboxGL from '@rnmapbox/maps';

MapboxGL.setAccessToken('pk.TOKEN');
export const MapScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={ styles.container }>
      <MapboxGL.MapView styleURL='mapbox://styles/arilith/ckr9r509238t817mxz75lwbxt' style={ styles.map }>


      </MapboxGL.MapView>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...GlobalStyles.pageContainer,
    padding: 0,
  },
  innerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 40,
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

EDIT: Or is there any way to view logs (in the emulator / expo) to see why it's hanging? As currently Expo just doesn't log anything when it hangs.

EDIT2: After some further investigation, this problem does not occur when the map is as a screen in a stack view while switching back and forwards. It looks like it has something to do with the use of the Tab Navigator...